# append rows to dataframe using foreach package

Tags: r, foreach, parallel-processing

I have a problem with appending values to a data frame using parallel processing.

I have a function that will do some calculation and return a dataframe, including these calculation is a random sampling.

so what i did is :

```
randomizex <- function(testdf)
{
    foreach(ind=1:1000)%dopar%
    {
      testdf$X = sample(testdf$X,nrow(testdf), replace=FALSE)
      fit = lm(X ~ Y, testdf)
      newdf <- rbind(newdf, data.frame(pc=ind, err=sum(residuals(fit)^2) ))

    }

return(newdf)
}
resdf = randomizex(mydf)
```

when i view the result of `resdf`, it's empty

if i replace `%dopar%` with `%do%` the result is calculated correctly but it's too slow ..

is there anyway to boost this a bit ??

Comment: remind us where `foreach` and `dopar` come from. And your `mydf` too - so we can reproduce your problem.

Comment: mydf is just a random dataframe, and foreach is a package and you should add `library(foreach)` and `library(doMC)`, `registerDoMC()`

Answer (score 21, accepted):

I think you need to read the docs for `foreach`. Your code block should compute a single part, then you should use the `.combine` option to say how to join them all together. Look at the examples in the `help(foreach)` for more guidance. Its not a straight replacement for a `for` loop.

For example:

```
> resultdf = foreach(i=1:10,.combine=rbind)%dopar%{data.frame(x=runif(4),i=i)}
> resultdf
            x  i
1  0.23794248  1
2  0.15536320  1
3  0.58609635  1
4  0.98780497  1
5  0.97806482  2
6  0.92440741  2
7  0.13416121  2
8  0.81598340  2
9  0.13834423  3
[etc]
```

Comment: ok, thank you for your answer, but how can i return the resulted df and use it somewhere else ?? it's just being printed to the stdou ..

Answer (score 5):

You need to modify your 'foreach loop' such as:

```
newdf = foreach(ind=1:1000, .combine=rbind) %dopar%
{
    testdf$X = sample(testdf$X,nrow(testdf), replace=FALSE)
    fit = lm(X ~ Y, testdf)
    data.frame(pc=ind, err=sum(residuals(fit)^2) )
}
```

Hope it helps!